# What would cause wicket page to load with page version of 1?

Tags: wicket-6

I am working on a wicket web Application using wicket 1.6.

Upon initial load of application I see page version in URL is set to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Why this is important? Framework has intensive internal live, sometimes 3 or 6 . Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at `org.apache.wicket.Session#nextPageId()` and see why it is called twice.